# Task is being scheduled on the same thread as the caller's

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, scheduler

My application has a View Model which contains a `Lazy<BitmapImage>` field. The field is populated using a service call to the server. In cases where the image is large, it takes a few seconds for the server to return the image (which is in fact a `byte[]`) therefore the UI is blocked. To prevent this, I put the service call in a `Task`, so that a background thread gets the image and then calls the `OnPropertyChanged` to let the UI know the image is returned:

```
Console.WriteLine("Outside Task ThreadID: {0}",
    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inside Task ThreadID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    return Utilities.ConvertByteToImage(
              SessionService.GetUserInformation(UserInfo.From).ProfilePicture);
}).ContinueWith(resultToken =>
{
    m_lazyProfilePicture = new Lazy<BitmapImage>(() =>
    {
        return (resultToken.Result == null) ? Utilities.DefaultProfilePicture.Value : resultToken.Result;
    });

    OnPropertyChanged("ProfilePicture");
});
```

I noticed that even after putting the service call in a `Task`, the UI is till blocked. So added those `Console.WriteLine` lines to see the thread IDs. Surprisingly enough, both of them report the same thread ID (this seems to happen only in this case.I tried it with other tasks in the project, and they all report different IDs). Any idea what's going on here? Does it have anything to do with the `BitmapImage`? For some reason the scheduler decides to put the task in the same thread, but I don't understand why. Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I think you're not using `Lazy` right. It's meant to be used when the delegate is expensive and you're okay when it blocks. But in your case, the delegate executes very quickly. You could have use just `BitmapImage` as the type of the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StartNew` doesn't ensure that the task is run in a new thread.  It uses `TaskScheduler.Current` to schedule the new task.  In many places throughout your code this will be `null`.  When it is `null`, then `TaskScheduler.Default` will be used, which will schedule the delegate to run in the thread pool.

In your particular case `Current` is not null.  It is the representation of some task scheduler that schedules the delegates to run in the UI thread.

One way this may have happened is if the code that you are running is the result of a call to `StartNew` or `ContinueWith` with the UI synchronization context.  During the delegates executed in either case it will set the current scheduler to be one that is based on the `SynchronizationContext` provided, namely the UI context.

If you use `Task.Run` you avoid the issue; it will always use the default task scheduler instead of the current one.

Your other option is to explicitly state you want the default task scheduler:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { }
    , CancellationToken.None
    , TaskCreationOptions.None
    , TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: Alright! Using the default scheduler did the trick. Another problem popped up now. I can't call the `OnPropertyChanged` method. It says `Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.` I tried to put `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` in the `ContinueWith` block, but it says `The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler.` I also tried dispatching it on both the Application.Current dispatcher and the caller's dispatcher. Any idea?

Comment: `BitmapImage.Freeze()` was required since the image was being created on a different thread but was being bound to in the UI thread. Also, `you are running is the result of a call to StartNew or ContinueWith with the UI synchronization context` was exactly the case. Thanks a lot!